# Why does MIX cause Callender's death?

Tags: comics, the-unwritten

In [The Unwritten #18](http://www.comicvine.com/the-unwritten-mix/37-238105/), Callender, the leader of the Unwritten, is killed by his aide because his aide received a piece of paper with "MIX" written on it.  Other than this presumably being a Roman numeral, 1009 (see page below), why does the aide stab Callender because of the piece of paper?   What link did this number have with Callender, if any?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the events of *Dead Man's Knock* (Storyline, not tpb) the Cabal meet and Mr callendar tries to blame Pullman for

> the fake Wilson Taylor novel scheme

He calls a vote.

> **Callendar:** Pullman has **failed** in his primary duty to the committee
>
> **Pullman:** This is [censored]
>
> **Callendar:** He should face the **Sibyl**. I call a vote

Pullman is sent down to the well. Protesting his "innocence"

> **Pullman:**(to Callendar) the fake novel was **your** plan, not mine

They begin the ceremony, Callendar explains the rules as he sees them.

> **Callendar:** Go to the **Sybil**, and put your hand in her mouth. If she gives a white ball he lives, a black ball we heave him over the edge.

The edge being the pit which Pullman is about to be put into. Firth (the aide) is sent to the Sybil.

> **Callendar:** Funny thing about the sybil, Pullman. I've never known her to spit out a white ball.

This implies that Callendar is only aware of (or considering) the two possibilities, the black ball (death) and the white ball (life). Whilst Firth goes to the Sybil, Pullman and Callendar have the following exchange:

> **Pullman:** Yeah? How far do you go **back**, Callendar?
>
> **Callendar:** Far enough. And you?
>
> **Pullman:** Me? I'm a whole different vintage

This tells us that even tho Callendar is Pullman's senior, Pullman has been in the cabal longer and has more knowledge, hence he is so calm over these precedings.

Firth visits the sybil and gets a third result, one that Callendar isn't aware of - a number. The MIX number.

> **Firth:** There was no **white ball**.
>
> **Callendar:** Good. Then let's **do** this.

Firth stabs Callendar and he falls into the pit.

> **Pullman:** Keep it **together** boy. Show them. Show them what she **gave** you.

Initially shocked, the rest of the people witnessing the event kneel when Firth shows the MIX paper.

> **Firth:** I **killed** him. That -- that was **right** wasn't it?
>
> **Pullman:** Of course it was right. The sybil told you his **number** was up.

So the short answer is that MIX was Callendar's number, and because the Sybil gave that number to Firth it indicated that he must die rather than Pullman (a black ball), indeed Callendar took the blame for the plot, rather than Pullman who he tried to make a scapegoat.

The pit image you've scanned also shows us that a number of other peoples number has come up. E.g. MVIII was someone else's number that came up.

Either Callendar was unaware of the 3rd possibility, or dismissed it as an improbability we don't know. Certainly Pullman's confidence in the scenario suggests that is what he expected to happen. Indeed, before Firth goes to the sybil he calmly says:

> **Pullman:** Last chance to back away from this Callendar

implying it is Callendar who is in danger not himself.

The concept of someones number being up is quite [common](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/number+is+up) in literary concepts, such as a bullet having your name on it "That bullet had my number on it".

Comment: So MIX was literally Callendar's number?  Out of curiousity, is this link made anywhere else in the comic?

Comment: That's my conclusion, yes. Other than Pullman's dialog this issue I don't think the link is explicitly made.

Comment: Interestingly, I've now found http://comicbookdb.com/character.php?ID=37322 which lists Callendar as the 1009th leader of the Unwritten, though I suspect that is speculation.